# Multisite Network Localisation

Tags: multisite, localization

The problem seems easy to solve - I have installed multisite network, each new page have Polish language set as default, polish localisation files are in right directory, in wp_config there is line:
define('WPLANG', 'pl_PL');
Sites admin panels are correctly in polish language, but global network admin isnt. 
What am I missing to turn network admin panel to polish language?

Comment: Did you try to re-save the language of the **#1** sub-site within *Settings » General*?

Comment: Men, You are genius :)
1rst site, site with #1, Settings -> WPLANG needs to be set.

Comment: Great! I added it as an answer so you can mark this question as solved :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-saving the language of the first site with the **ID #1** solved the problem.

One can do this within *Settings » General » Site Language*